# Bootstrap 3 closing dropdown after click problems with IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to close via jQuery my Bootstrap 3 drop down after clicking on an list item.

html

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">10 <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0)">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0)">20</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.header').on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var number = $(this).text(),
    $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.btn').html(number + " <span class=\"caret\"></span>");
    $(this).dropdown("toggle"); // Use for close dropdown on click

});
```

Unfortunately this solution does not work well with IE and Chrome.
In fact, after that I ran a few times the choice, the drop down stops show elements.

With Firefox it seems to work without problems.
How can I solve my problem?

Thank you

EDIT

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvq6ucqq/)

I noticed that even with firefox I have the same problems

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for this question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have my same problem I found a trick to solve it.

Use

```
$("body").trigger("click");
```

in place of

```
$(this).dropdown("toggle");
```